# How to jump to specific page in PageView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two Stateful Widget classes. In one of them is a PageView. I have no problem going between pages in this pageview. I have a setstate with an int which holds the position of the current page and a controller on the pageview. From my second class I have one of these 
`Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SwitchPages()));`

This call brings me back to the first page of the pageview, but id like to go to a different page. Im sure theres a simple way but ive tried

```
setState(() {
          ind = 1;
          controller.jumpToPage(1);
        });
```

But it gives me an error that the controller has not been assigned and there are no positions. Any sugguestions?

Comment: Are you assigning it using `PageView(controller: controller)`?

Comment: yep, heres the error : 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 110 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty': ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.

Comment: restart the app /share some more code